# VBA error: "Runtime Error 1004: Application defined or object defined error"

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a complete newbie at vba and coding in general and am following along with a vba course on udemy at the moment. During one of the exercises (dynamic sorting) i keep getting the above mentioned error. It's quite frustrating being stuck like this while following the teacher exactly.. Any help is appreciated.

```
Sub Sort()
'
' Sort Macro
'
ThisWorkbook.Activate

Range("a2").Select

'find last row

mylr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1up).Row


ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("C2:C5"),    _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:C5")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What line is throwing the error? I'd rather not guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't want to take you away from the flow of your lesson plan but that looks like recorded code from a manual sorting operation which is terribly verbose. In reality, all you need is the following.

I would recommend you get into the practise of either setting the VBE's Tools ► Options ► Editor ► [Require variable declaration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke6sh835.aspx) or manually putting `Option Explicit`¹ at the top of each module code sheet. Currently, the **x1up** constant was left misspelled.

```
Sub mySort()
    ' Sort Macro

    'reference the workbook and worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1")
        'reference the range to receive the sorting method
        With .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2))
            'sort the cells based on the third column in a descending order
            .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(3), Order1:=xlDescending, _
                        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Never name your sub procedure the same as a **reserved word**. This effectively overwrites the functionality of that command or constant in favor of the newer name. By naming your function `Sub Sort()` and then trying to call the [Range.Sort method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840646.aspx) your sub procedure can be in a position to effectively try to recall itself.

---

¹ <sub>Setting **Require Variable Declaration** within the VBE's Tools ► Options ► Editor property page will put the **[Option 
Explicit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9341s4f.aspx)** statement at the top of each newly created code sheet. This 
will avoid silly coding mistakes like misspellings as well as influencing you to use the correct variable type in the variable 
declaration. Variables created on-the-fly without declaration are all of the variant/object type. Using **Option Explicit** is 
widely considered 'best practice'.</sub>

Comment: Thanks Jeeped! As I said I'm a complete beginner so thanks for your patience and understandable response. I should of mentioned the particular lesson I was doing was introducing the record macro function. It's not the basis of the whole course by any means.

Answer (score 2):

Error in line ?

```
mylr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(x1up).Row
```

By the way, myLr use for what?

Comment: Good eye for the `1` vs `l` problem. The code itself has major issues beyond that.

Comment: Hi. To find the last row in the column.

Comment: Oke... to find the last row in the column. But since that value never used in your function, so it useless. Bug might be come from it. Just delete that line, your function will be OK.